# Python Fast Open File Only Need To Compare Bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
bytes = "abc123"
with open(file, 'rb') as in:
    info = struct.unpack('<H', in.read(struct.calcsize('<H')))[0]
    info2 = infile.read(info)
    if info2 == SIGNATURE:
        return
```

How can I open files quickly in a for loop ~10k files I just need 6-10 first bytes to verify if the file was encrypted before and skip it if possible to open only X bytes and this will be quickly for each file?

Comment: There's no such thing as "opening only X bytes".  If you're already only *reading* X bytes, you're probably doing as much as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BrenBarn commented, there isn't much more to do. I would change your script to the following:

```
bytes = "abc123"
read_size = struct.calcsize('<H')
with open(file, 'rb') as infile:
    info, = struct.unpack('<H', infile.read(read_size))
    info2 = infile.read(info)
    if info2 == SIGNATURE:
        return
```

The changes are minor and probably won't make a significant difference in execution time since your bottleneck is in opening 10k files, but avoiding unnnecesary function/method calls is always nice, and picking the first element with info, is a tiny bit faster than than using [0].

**Edit:** just noticed the with statement said in instead of infile in the original code. Also, fixed both read calls to use the correct variable.

Comment: thank you I will add this small changes to my code but will still look for some way to start "x" dir in os.walk or write all files to file and check if it's not included in it to not encrypt it or something

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Python limitation but a file system and operating system limitation.

If you need to speed up the operation then it is better to collect or index the data to some fast access structure in the database in the first place, instead of trying to access it in raw format.

Comment: what can you suggest can you be more specfic text file/json I'm windows? or maybe because I'm using os.walk to find the dirs/files I can write down the last dir I was in to some place and next time continue from that point? Not sure if os.walk allow to start from "x" dir hmm

Comment: Don't put your data to files. Use a database like MySQL or SQLite instead.